# Rails LoadError: cannot load such file -- action_view/template/error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline, actionview

I've just setup a simple rails application, with Devise and some contents pages (basically simple html).
Everything works, but after few minutes the server start responding with this at each request:

> Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4.2ms
>
> LoadError (cannot load such file -- action_view/template/error):
>   app/middleware/catch_json_parse_errors.rb:8:in `call'

If I restart the server, then everything works for some minutes, then the problem come back again.

I'm using ruby 2.0.0-p353, rails 3.2.16, and Thin as web server.
I'm launching the server in development mode and without precompiling assets.

Answer (score 0):

It seems Thin catches a broken JSON object. You may want to take a look at this link.
http://robots.thoughtbot.com/catching-json-parse-errors-with-custom-middleware